# Creating Polygon using Google Map API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am referring the URL : https://housing.com/in/buy/search?f=eyJiYXNlIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoiUE9MWSIsInV1aWQiOiJmMGZhNTIwNjI0ZjNhOGRlOWY4NSIsImxhYmVsIjoiUGltcGxlIFNhdWRhZ2FyIn1dLCJ2IjoyLCJzIjoiZCJ9

I am trying to make something similar, can anybody suggest how can I achieve it. I tried to search and explore google map APIs, but could not understand which API in particular can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the [Google Maps Showcase](https://developers.google.com/maps/showcase/). Millions of apps and sites are using Google Maps APIs. Browse the showcase to see some of our favorite implementations.

You can use the MarkerClusterer library in combination with the Google Maps JavaScript API to combine markers of close proximity into clusters, and simplify the display of markers on the map.

Here's a sample project for MarkerCluster: https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclusterer

Comment: Thanks @LenovoS90, do you know which of the APIs will be helpful to build polygons from a location

Answer (score 0):

Polygon is one feature of Drawing tools of Google Maps. The `DrawingManager` class provides a graphical interface for users to draw polygons, rectangles, polylines, circles, and markers on the map.

The Drawing Tools are a self-contained library, separate from the main Maps API JavaScript code. To use the functionality contained within this library, you must first load it using the libraries parameter in the Maps API bootstrap URL:

`<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=drawing">
</script>`

Once you’ve added the libraries parameter, you can create a DrawingManager object as follows:

`var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager();
drawingManager.setMap(map);`

Reference: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/drawing-tools

Comment: Thanks for the reply : But I am looking for passing a place name and polygon should be located in Map. If I pass like Bangalore, it should highlight in the map.